# Filtering nested array in Mongo Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

Following NoSQL query returns all reviews of a particular user :

```
db.getCollection('catalog-review').aggregate([
{
     $project: {
       reviews: {
         $filter: {
           input: "$reviews",
           as: "review",
           cond: { $eq: [ "$$review.userId", 121 ] }
          }
        }
      }
}
])
```

This is query works fine but if I implement this in Java using Mongo driver, the "$$" doesn't work.

```
List<CatalogReview> reviews = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$project", new Document("reviews", new Document("$filter", new Document("input", "$reviews")
                    .append("as", "review").append("cond", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList(new Document("$$review.userId", 121)))))))
    )).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

The error message:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 15999: 'invalid operator '$$review.userId'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$$review.userId'", "code" : 15999 }
```

Does Mongo driver supports aggregate functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `Arrays.asList(new Document("$$review.userId", 121))`. It should be `Arrays.asList("$$review.userId", 121)`.

`Arrays.asList(new Document("$$review.userId", 121))` = `[ { "$$review.userId" : 121 } ]`

`Arrays.asList("$$review.userId", 121)` = `[  "$$review.userId", 121  ]`

The snippet should be like below:

```
List<CatalogReview> reviews = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$project", new Document("reviews", new Document("$filter", new Document("input", "$reviews")
                    .append("as", "review").append("cond", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$review.userId", 121))))))
    )).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you.